using curl to access the API
when I use a curl command to send json-rpc requst. I get prompted for a username and password  but afterwards I get no response.
Do I need to run a full node in order to do Bitcoin mining?


when I use a curl command to send json-rpc requst. I get prompted for a username and password but afterwards I get no response.

Perhaps your node is busy with Initial Block Download (IBD) and curl has a time-out whose default is shorter than needed for Bitcoin core under load

Do I need to run a full node in order to do Bitcoin mining?

You mainly need to spend several thousand dollars (or local equivalent) on the latest bleeding-edge ASICs and support infrastructure. I can't think of any reason why a pruning node wouldn't be adequate for use in conjunction with mining. A pruning node also needs to download the entire blockchain so this probably  doesn't help with response timeouts, just disk space.
